# Android : download files list from Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded a file list to Firebase that I want to download using my app.

```
List<String> childsRef = new ArrayList<>();
childsRef.add("xxxx/img1");    
childsRef.add("xxxx/img2");
... etc
```

Then, through this list, I try to download files using my Firebase storageReference :

```
for (String child : childsRef) {
    islandRef = storageRef.child(child);
    File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
    islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
       // Local temp file has been created
       }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
       // Handle any errors
       }
 });
}
```

The download process is async, so I can't show pop-ups to visualize downloading progression... I want to navigate to next Activity only if all of pending downloads are done..

Do you have any ideas/help?

--EDIT
Solution :

```
FirebaseStorage instance = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference referenceFromUrl = instance.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxxxx.appspot.com/");

for (final String aur : aurl) {
    final File localFile = new File(PATH + aur.substring(aur.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, aur.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".dat");

    StorageReference f = referenceFromUrl.child(aur);

    FileDownloadTask task = f.getFile(localFile);

    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            size += localFile.length();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            Log.e("firebase ", ";local tem file not created  created " + exception.toString());
        }
    });

    while (!task.isComplete()) {
    }

    publishProgress("" + (int) ((float) i++ * 100 / aurl.length));

}
```

Comment: That loop `while (!task.isComplete())` is not a really good idea.  You're making this thread consume 100% CPU while it waits for the download to complete.  It's far better to collect all the tasks from all the downloads and pass them all to Tasks.waitAll() to get a single task that you can wait on for completion, as I recommended in my answer.

Comment: There are no "Tasks.waitAll()" method, should I loop through this list and call Tasks.await() ?

Comment: Yes, there is.  I linked to the javadoc for it in my answer.

Comment: You lindek whenAll()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getFile returns a [FileDownloadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask.html) object, which is a subclass of [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).  As you probably know, this Task tracks the progress of the download.  You have the option of kicking off all the downloads at once, collecting all the Tasks in a list, then using [Tasks.whenAll()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E)) to get a new Task that completes when all the downloads are complete.

I have a [four part blog series](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html) about using Tasks that might help you better understand how they work.

Comment: Thank you ! I updated my answer to show the solution

Comment: @Mohamed Where is your answer?

Answer (score 0):

make childsRef hashmap and add a boolean to see if download is completed.
set value true when onSuccess and make a handler to send message when a download completed to check if all boolean values true. than start your activity from handler.